# Error Opening Datalab Notebooks (All Files!) No Dataflow Connection

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Today I started up my VM and went to open one of my note books and got the following error:

> Type u'notebook&_=1495504519954' is invalid

I have now tried numerous notebooks.  They are all coming back with a similar error. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you see the error? What happens when you create a new notebook?

Comment: I get the same error with clicking the link to create a new notebook.  I also get the same error from a brand new datalab instance created wit datalab create <vm>.  I see the error as it loads the notebook file.

Comment: To add two other facts to the equation: I too can open the readme.ipynb  but I note that it has no code blocks.  Also, I opened a couple of the .ipynb files from the shell and the json data itself within looks intact. (at least to the eye)

Comment: One last factoid.  When you click to start a new notebook.  You get the same error as above.  When you click OK to the error dialog, you get an open notebook window.  If you click to add a code block.  It adds something, but it appears to add a markdown block.  If you try to save it the status bar says "Autosave Failed".  If you close this tab and go back to the directory tab.  It shows file created.  Unlike normal, when you close a notebook, the status indicator next to the dir listing shows green, instead the Untitled Notebook.ipynb shows a gray indicator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an "Error loading notebook" error when trying to set up DataFlow and do image classification on Cloud ML Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127178/why-am-i-getting-an-error-loading-notebook-error-when-trying-to-set-up-dataflo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to happen when connecting to Datalab using Cloud Shell, and should now be fixed.

Updates will be here: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1377

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me today too - was working great yesterday... I can open the Readme, but none of the tutorial notebooks or the one I was happily working on yesterday. Later on in the day I made a copy of one of the notebooks I was interested in and it started fine...