# Why am I getting an "Error loading notebook" error when trying to set up Datalab and do image classification on Cloud ML Engine?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am following the tutorial here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-ml-engine-image-classification/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

and it is claiming that it will allow me to do image classification on the google cloud. I follow the instructions but when I get to step 4 where I "Start a datalab notebook". It tells me to open the docs folder in Google Cloud DataLab and then open the file called: Hello World.ipynb.

WHen I open this file I get a really weird error that I can't find anything googling. The error is a modal that says:

```
Error loading notebook

Type u'notebook&_=1495520163792' is invalid
```

No code loads either from the file. What the heck??? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to happen when connecting to Datalab using Cloud Shell, and should now be fixed.

Updates will be here: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1377

Answer (score 1):

There are two other ways of starting Datalab (the codelab above assumes option #1):

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb100-datalab/index.html

Perhaps you will have better luck following Option 2, to run it from CloudShell.  Once Datalab is launched, you should be able to continue with the original codelab.

Answer (score 1):

Can you browse http://localhost:8081/_info and paste the debug information here if possible?

Also, can you create a new Datalab notebook from the "Notebook" menu?